# Filling a combobox with years

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF project and I have a years combobox that should contain years from 1950 to present year. Any ideas how proceed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write a loop that starts at 1950 and ends at the current year. For every iteration of this loop just add an entry to the combobox with the current loop counter as content.

Some pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 1950; i <= currentYear; i++) {
   ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
   item.Content = i;
   myCombobox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

How about something like this, assign it as DataSource

```
Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.Today.Year).ToList();
```

Comment: 2nd parameter is the count of numbers to be added to the initial number 1950. Correct is 'Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1949).ToList();' This will include current year in the list.

Comment: Sorry this answer doesn't work at all, it will fill a list from 1950~3972 thousands years. The comment from Pollack solves it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
for(int year = 1950; year<DateTime.UtcNow.Year; ++year)
{
// Add year as year to the combo box item source...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with current year by adding Reverse. Also Enumerable Range requires using System.Linq.

```
Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 1949).Reverse().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 1950; i <= 2050; i++)
        {              

           Year_combo.Items.Add(i);
        }
```